# Checkbox stores only in the Database when all of the available checkboxes are checked

Tags: checkbox

Is this a valid code?

```
<div class="checkbox-container">    
  <?php foreach($offices as $destination) :?>
    <div class="checkbox-office">
       <label for="checkbox"><?= $destination['OfficeName']?></label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="<?= $destination['InputName']?>" value="<?= $destination['InputValue']?>">
    </div>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Because everytime I check one of the checkboxes an error appears when you click submit and it only successfully store the data if I check all of the checkboxes.

the errors always said undefined index input-records even though the name is already display vi $destination['InputName'] in wamp

I tried recoding it with isset still nothing happens.